# Base case of a recurrence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

$T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + 1,  \text{if n > 2, and T(n) = 0 otherwise}$

For the above problem, how would I tell the base case if it's not given explicitly? Since it says $n>2$ So would that mean $T(3)= C $?

Comment: But it **is** given explicitly; that's the _"T(n) = 0 otherwise"_ part.

Comment: Well, I tried to use that base case and solve using iterative substitution but got a 0 at the end. Can I assume T(3) = some random number and use that as a base case?

Comment: $T(2)=0$ so I got $$T(n)=\frac{\log \log n-\log \log 2}{\log 2}$$